# OpenGL: How to drag image and move it to the line by using the mouse

Tags: c, opengl

I want to drag an image to one line by using the mouse and when the image is close to the line, the image will automatically move on to the line, like some `"floor planner"` program ------------you create wall and drag the door to this wall and when the door is close to the wall, the door will automatically show up on the wall.

Can OpenGL do it?

if it can, can anyone tell me how?  If it can not, can anyone tell me how I can do it?
Show me an example.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you are asking how to make an object follow the mouse, and if close to another object (or line) to snap it on to it, right?

Comment: Do you know How to do it?

Comment: @nightcracker Do you know how?

Answer (score 5):

OpenGL is a rendering API, it's purpose is to generate rasterized images based on descriptions provided to it by an application.

It knows nothing about user input, and even less about the application's "domain objects" such as doors, walls, and so on. All it deals with is abstract coordinates and matrices that describe the transforms and projections to take those 3D coordinates into 2D for rasterization, as well as shading for surfaces and so on.

So, it's up to you to implement that, so that the coordinates you eventually pass to OpenGL end up being what you want them to be.

Snapping is typically a combination of *measuring* the distance to some guiding object, and the following *quantization* of the input coordinates to correspond to the the guide.

Comment: Well, Yes I got it! How can I find the side of an object, I mean I made a square how can I find the coordinates of this square?

Comment: @user2099155: By calculating it. OpenGL doesn't maintain a scene or such. It just draws things. You'll have to do the selection math yourself.